# !obfuscate command Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, discord

I am currently making a discord bot for my exploiting community. I am trying to make a !obfuscate command for Roblox Lua. I have tried many of things but I can't seem to get it right. I have only seen 1 thread on here for a Discord Bot that can receive files. For example, I do the command, "!obfuscate". After doing that, it will send an embed saying you have to send a file. I send a file but I keep getting errors. This is my code.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'obfuscate',
    description: "obfuscates your files",
    execute(message, args, Discord){
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('CypherBrew Obfuscator')
    .setDescription('To obfuscate, please send a file with the extension, .txt or .lua. If not, obfuscation will not work.')
    .setFooter('If you want this to be private, please DM the bot.');
    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    let filter = m => m.author == message.author;
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1}).then(message => {
    let file = message.attachments.first().file;
    if (!file) return;
      fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
            const nooo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('CypherBrew Obfuscator')
            .setDescription('File has been obfuscated! Thank you for using CypherBrew Obfuscator.')
            .setFooter('Epic, you obfuscated a file. lol.');
            message.Channel.send(nooo);
            message.Channel.send(data);
      });
    });
    }
}
```

My error is this. "Type Error: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined". I got the code from a 2 year old post but Discord JS has updated. I have been looking for severs and people and asking my same question in them but I never get a good answer. Most of them are broken. If you help me out, thanks.

Comment: Any relevance? https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/docs/examples/attachments.md

Comment: @AntonKrug

Somewhat relevant. Instead of the bot actually sending the file, I want to send the file and it will read its data.